# Cannot understand error: "warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]"

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, return, compiler-warnings

I have been learning c++ recently. When I tried to run the following lines...

```
#include <iostream>

short a = 0;
short b = 1;
short c, i;

void Fibonacci(){
    std::cout << a;
    std::cout << b;
    while (a <= 100){
        c = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = c;
        std::cout << c;
    }
}

int prime_number(short a){
    if (a == 1){
        std::cout << "It's a prime number\n";
    } else{
        for (i = 2; i < a; i++){
            if ((a%i) == 0){
                std::cout << "It's a prime number\n";
                std::cout << "The given number is divisible by " << i << "\n";
                return 0;    
            }
        }
        std::cout << "It's not an prime number";
    }
}

int main(){
    short user_input;
    std::cout << "Press 1 for Fibonacci and 2 for prime number";
    std::cin >> user_input;

    if (user_input == 1){
        Fibonacci();
    }
    if (user_input == 2){
        std::cout << "Type the number to check whether it's prime";
        std::cin >> a ;
        prime_number(a);
    }
}
```

...I get an error saying:

```
In function ‘int prime_number(short int)’:
Function.cpp:37:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
   37 | }
```

I searched various platforms for the answers, but I couldn't understand what really happens here. It's an error because the compiler cannot find whether the function has an end or not. Can someone help me understand the error and solve it?

Comment: now I could understand the warning clearly. Thanks for the help

Comment: No problem. Generally stackoverflow isn't designed to be beginner-friendly - at least when it comes to posting new questions. It's designed to be a repository of unique questions and their answers - and (pretty well) all the beginner questions have already been asked. I'm not sure what website is best for complete beginners, but while you're still learning the basics I'd only post a question here as a last-resort. It can be tough in the beginning - hopefully you have friends/teachers who can help you there; otherwise, maybe try Quora? Best of luck.  =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Elliott in the comments has said the warning you are getting is not going to affect your program at all. It's recommend that you return something since you function has a return type of integer.

Below is a easy fix to get rid of the warning. :)

**Old Code:**

```cpp
if (a == 1)
{
    std::cout << "Its a prime number\n";
}
```

**New Code without the Warning:**

```cpp
if (a == 1)
{
    std::cout << "Its a prime number\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "the warning you are getting is not going to affect your program at all" - that is incorrect, see https://godbolt.org/z/MGqKafE5e - can you figure out where the final "The given number is divisible by something" is coming from?

Comment: (the preceding comment was brought to you by the `-Werror=return-type` campain)

Comment: @dratenik, for the record: I'm being quoted here as saying that, but those weren't my words. I was just pointing out that the "error" message was actually a warning. Nice demo code, btw.

Answer (score 2):

Warnings aren't errors. When you compile a program and only get warnings (ie. no errors) then this means your program has successfully compiled (an executable has been made). When you get errors, this means that compilation was aborted (so no executable output - if you already had one, it won't have been updated).

It's warning you that when the integer input is `1` that you aren't specifying a `return` — which is invalid. Also, if it's ***not*** `1`, then the the `else` statement still doesn't guarantee a `return`ed value:

```
for (i = 2; i < a; i++){
    if ((a%i) == 0){
        std::cout << "it's a prime number\n";
        std::cout << "The given number is divisible by " << i << "\n";
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The compiler can't know that `return 0` will always be executed here - and even if it could, the compiler isn't designed to always understand the logic of your code. Even knowing your logic, `return 0` will only be executed if `a` is greater than `2` and non-prime.

You ***could*** fix this by putting `return` statements in both of your `if` statements, or even at the end of your function. But notice that you never use the return value? This implies that your `prime_number()` function should be `void prime_number()`, then you won't need return values at all, and can just use `break;` in your loop - or `return;` if you prefer (here's [an example](https://godbolt.org/z/rnh3jEM6Y) of how to resolve this particular issue - there's still other bugs though, discussed below).

This is probably confusing to a beginner: Why doesn't it warn you when the function `int main()` contains no return value? This is because `main` is ***special***: If no return value is given, it implies `return 0`.

Another thing that may confuse you here is if you ever compile with the flag `-Werror`. If you do, then the original code will give you an error, because the `Werror` flag turns all warnings into errors (to force programmers to pay attention to the warnings).

The logic of your code isn't right - it's actually the opposite: `1` is defined as not a prime number (this is because of the value we get from ***unique*** [prime decomposition](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/prime-power-decomposition), so mathematicians chose to exclude `1` as prime). Also, `((a%i) == 0)` means that when `a` is divided by `i` that it has `0` remainder, ie. `i` divides `a`, so `a` is ***not*** prime.

Finally, avoid using [global variables](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-are-global-variables-in-Cplusplus). Keep all your variables [local](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_variable_scope.htm) so that the logic of your code is simpler (easier to read / less bug-prone).

[Here's an example of how you could rewrite your code](https://godbolt.org/z/913j6s79q) that resolves all the above issues.